# How to get the watchpoint breakpoint info after kernel hit a watchpoint breakpoint on arm

Tags: debugging, gdb, arm

On X86 platform, debugger like gdb could set a watchpoint breakpoint using register R0~R3, and the register R7 stores the breakpoint information. Once kernel hit a watchpoint breakpoint, the debugger could collect the watchpoint breakpoint info, read the information from register R6, R6's bit[0]~bit[3] could indicate the watchpoint index(R0 or R1 or R2 or R3) using **dr[6]&0xf**.

But on arm platform, how to get this information, seems we don't have a register like R6 on X86 platform.